# How use RAISERROR without stop inserted/updated on trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, raiserror

I need use `RAISERROR` in my system, but when I use it, RAISERROR stopped inserted/updated action. I need use `RAISERROR` but with inserted/updated.

```
--previous trigger code
IF (@flag = 0)
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Warning!! You need add Price', 11, 0)
END
```

After of the message popup, the inserted/updated is cancel. I used severity values, but show message and don't save or don't show message and save. I need show message and save.

Comment: `RAISERROR`, in and of itself does not cause a transaction rollback. If something is performing a rollback, it's some more of your own code. We can't wave a magic wand.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Also do not use RAISERROR function to implement your business logic, business logic should be handled in the application layer. When collecting the information from end user, if the user hasn't provided "Price" handle that in application layer and show a message to end-user there and then, no need to go to the database and then create a message in sql server only to send it all the way back to the end-user etc etc, you get the point, don't you :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and comment!